# AWS API Gateway returns 403 when XML versio header is present in xml body

Tags: xml, amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

I have API Gateway endpoint that calls API on ECS.
Endpoint is supposed to receive XML and parse it internally.
The problem is no matter what model I used for request body (or even without body defined at all) API GW returns 403 when XML version is present in request.

This one causes API GW to return 403:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<billing_info_updated_notification>
  <account>
    test
  </account>
</billing_info_updated_notification>
```

and this one works (no xml version header):

```xml
<billing_info_updated_notification>
  <account>
    test
  </account>
</billing_info_updated_notification>
```

Any idea how to fix this? The problem is that this is webhook notification so I dont have any control on shape of xml.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was with AWS WAF enabled :(.
WAF blocked all requests with body starting with:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

Disabling WAF "solved" the issue.

Comment: It is from AWS WAF XSS rule body scanning rule, instead of disabling it, you might want to create a  whitelist rule based on certain conditions.

Answer (score 1):

> Check your Amazon VPC to confirm if you created an interface VPC endpoint to access a >private API Gateway API. If there's an interface endpoint, see if the private DNS setting is selected.

See [Docs](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/api-gateway-vpc-connections/)